# "Unhandled 'error' event " or How to deploy meteor app with mup on NGINX?

Tags: javascript, nginx, meteor, mup

I want to build a Meteor app with MUP to an NGINX powered server. Half a year ago, I made it, and everything was fine, but now I got this error:

```
events.js:141
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event 
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 188.166.60.237:22
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:930:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1081:14)
```

Here is my MUP.js:

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      // TODO: set host address, username, and authentication method
      host: 'myHostIp',
      username: 'root',
      // pem: './path/to/pem'
      password: 'password'
      // or neither for authenticate from ssh-agent
    }
  },

  app: {
    // TODO: change app name and path
    name: 'realmotion',
    path: '../',

    servers: {
      one: {}
    },

    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
    },

    env: {
      // TODO: Change to your app's url
      // If you are using ssl, it needs to start with https://
      PORT:'8080',
      ROOT_URL: 'https://realmotion.io',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor'
    },

    // ssl: { // (optional)
    //   // Enables let's encrypt (optional)
    //   autogenerate: {
    //     email: 'email.address@domain.com',
    //     // comma separated list of domains
    //     domains: 'website.com,www.website.com'
    //   }
    // },

    docker: {
      // change to 'kadirahq/meteord' if your app is using Meteor 1.3 or older
      image: 'kadirahq/meteord'
    },

    // Show progress bar while uploading bundle to server
    // You might need to disable it on CI servers
    enableUploadProgressBar: true,
    deployCheckWaitTime: 80
  },

  mongo: {
    version: '3.2.12',
    port: 27017,
    servers: {
      one: {}
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you manually run `ssh -v <username>@<host_ip>` and share the output?

Comment: Has the ip address of the server changed?

Comment: @DerekBrown here:
`root@server-main:~# ssh -v <root>@<188.***.***.237>
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'`

Comment: @Mikkel nope it wasn't

Comment: @OyshoBoy the angle brackets are just placeholders.  The command you should run is `ssh -v root@188.***.***.237`

Comment: @DerekBrown oh yes, checked, discovered that problem was in ports, they was blocked by firewall.
But now i have this:
error - https://pastebin.com/Yidtedzk,  
logs - https://pastebin.com/jztMuig6

Comment: @OyshoBoy that looks like an error in your actual meteor code.     Just for documentation sake- can you open this as a new question with the relevant code and tag me in it?

Comment: @OyshoBoy is makes it easier for people Googling these answers down the road to fix their own issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to document this for others in the future- this error was caused because the SSH ports were being blocked by the firewall.  Make sure your deployment host is accessible via SSH.

How to do this will depend on your particular system; Ubuntu (depending on version) will require a commend to `ufw` or `iptables`, RHEL family would require either `firewallctl` or `iptables`.  Simply lookup firewall documentation for your particular system.